# Broken Firefox add-on update

Tags: firefox-addon

We are providing updates to our Firefox add-on on our own http site. Due to an error in the manual signing process with McCoy, a version of the add-on was published with the wrong public key in its install.rdf. We don't have the matching private key to sign the update.rdf. The Firefox update manager is now silently ignoring our updates.

Is there a way to tell the update manager to notify prominently our users of the problem, and suggest they install the fixed version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it is not possible.

Comment: Thank you, this confirms my fears. We will have to find a less elegant solution.